# How to render an epub with a specific package

Tags: react-native, epub

I downloaded a package to render epub in react-native, but it is just rendering .opf file, like the example on github:

```
<SafeAreaView>
      <ReaderProvider>
        <Reader
          src={{ uri: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moby-dick/OPS/package.opf' }}
          width={width}
          height={height}
        />
      </ReaderProvider>
    </SafeAreaView>
```

Here is the package I am using: https://github.com/victorsoares96/epubjs-react-native

**I need to render an epub file located inside my application.**

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
<SafeAreaView>
  <ReaderProvider>
    <Reader
      src={require('./src/books/book1.epub'}
      width={width}
      height={height}
    />
  </ReaderProvider>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Does anyone know why I'm not getting it?

Comment: I dont think that it can read a local location. Try using `react-native-fs` and convert the file to base64 and pass it to src. it should work